# Disable certificate revocation check for specific HTTPS connections on Windows

Tags: windows, go, ssl, https, schannel

I'm working on a internet restricted environment. Since our internal services we are using Let's Encrypt certificates to avoid the overhead with an internal PKI.

I'm writing a go program which collects informations from all systems and sent the data to a central system. While this works fine for Linux systems, have I have trouble on Windows system.

It seems like that go is using the os native libraries to establish a secured connection for HTTPS requests.

With using the program below

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    htmlData, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", resp.Status)
    fmt.Printf(string(htmlData))
}
```

I'm getting an handshake timeout

```
2023/09/13 16:19:03 Get "https://google.de": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

It seems like the native libraries tries to contact the CRLs (which are not allowed) and the connection fails here. I inspect the traffic with Wireshark and see HTTP connection to `r3.c.lencr.org` with User-Agent CryptoAPI.

I also can verify such behavior, if I'm using curl

```
curl https://google.de
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

However curl has the option `--ssl-no-revoke` to skip the specific revoke check. Running curl with the option works fine.

How I can configure go to skip the revoke check? I'm not looking an option that skips the entire ssl validation.

I tried look into the TLSConfig of go, but I could not find such an option.

Comment: For curl _using schannel_ (i.e. the MS-distributed port, not another version like wsl or gitbash/mingw) you can use commandline option `--ssl-no-revoke` but I don't know about go

Comment: You meant you «tried to look into the `tls.Config`», did you? If so, did setting `InsecureSkipVerify` help?

Comment: @kostix `InsecureSkipVerify` does skip all checks which is a non acceptable. Please take of my second last paragraph.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the quote. The option is included on my post, too.